# Evaluate a power series by relating it to a geometric series (where coefficients depend on the index of summation).

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the power series $f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}n^{2}z^{n}$ by relating it to a geometric series. By the ratio test, the series converges (absolutely) for $\left|z\right|<1$.

I assume it's not as simple as writing $f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(n^{2/n}z\right)^{n}$?

Should I proceed as in the case of the standard geometric series, i.e., by writing down an expression for the $m$th partial sum and then taking the limit as $m\to\infty$?

Comment: The usual approach to things like this is to start with the geometric series, differentiate it, and manipulate the result.

Comment: Great! And differentiating through the sum in the geometric series is justified since the series is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of the unit disc $D_{1}\left(0\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the fact that
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n\geq 0} x^n$$
(This is the simplest formula for an infinite geometric series)
Differentiate to obtain
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0} nx^{n-1}$$
and multiply by $x$:
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0} nx^{n}$$
Repeat the top two steps and you get a closed formula
$$\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n\geq 0} n^2 x^{n-1}$$
$$\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n\geq 0} n^2 x^{n}$$
Therefore,
$$f(z) = \frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}$$

Comment: Great! And, to justify differentiating the geometric series term-by-term, we use the fact that the series is absolutely convergent for $\left|z\right|<1$ and therefore uniformly convergent for $\left|z\right|\leq\rho$, for all $\rho<1$?

Answer (score 0):

There is another similar way to do it using the small trick $n^2=n(n-1)+n$
$$f(z)=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty n^2 x^n=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty [n(n-1)+n] x^n$$
$$f(z)=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty n(n-1) x^n+\sum_{n= 0}^\infty n x^n=x^2\sum_{n= 0}^\infty n(n-1) x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n= 0}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$
$$f(z)=x^2 \left(\sum_{n= 0}^\infty  x^{n} \right)''+x \left(\sum_{n= 0}^\infty  x^{n} \right)'$$

The smae would have been applied if you had $n^3$ or $n^4$ instead of $n^2$ since
$$n^3=n(n-1)(n-2)+3n(n-1)+n$$
$$n^4=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+6n(n-1)(n-2)+7n(n-1)+n$$